# Makefile: how to set a LOGFILE=`date +'test_%m.%d_%H.%M.%S.log'` variable only once?

Tags: makefile

I like to log output of test program to a log file with time stamp.

I created following Makefile, but it doesn't work.  The "make" seems to calculate LOGFILE at the last moment as needed.

**Makefile**

```
LOGFILE=`date +'test_%m.%d_%H.%M.%S.log'`
export DLOG=$(LOGFILE)
test2:
    echo DLOG=$$DLOG
    echo DLOG=${DLOG}
    sleep 2
    echo DLOG=${DLOG}
```

**make test2**

```
echo DLOG=$DLOG
DLOG=`date +'test_%m.%d_%H.%M.%S.log'`
echo DLOG=`date +'test_%m.%d_%H.%M.%S.log'`
DLOG=test_10.22_10.28.04.log
sleep 2
echo DLOG=`date +'test_%m.%d_%H.%M.%S.log'`
DLOG=test_10.22_10.28.06.log
```

I like to find someway to have the "make" calculate the LOGFILE or DLOG variable only once and I can use the same value everywhere in the makefile.   Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the *flavor* of your variable.

The manual section in question is [The Two Flavors of Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors).

Specifically

> The first flavor of variable is a *recursively expanded* variable. Variables of this sort are defined by lines using ‘=’ (see [Setting Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Setting)) or by the define directive (see [Defining Multi-Line Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multi_002dLine)). The value you specify is installed verbatim; if it contains references to other variables, these references are expanded whenever this variable is substituted (in the course of expanding some other string). When this happens, it is called *recursive expansion*.

and

> To avoid all the problems and inconveniences of recursively expanded variables, there is another flavor: simply expanded variables.
>
> *Simply expanded variables* are defined by lines using ‘:=’ or ‘::=’ (see [Setting Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Setting)). Both forms are equivalent in GNU make; however only the ‘::=’ form is described by the POSIX standard (support for ‘::=’ was added to the POSIX standard in 2012, so older versions of make won’t accept this form either).

So you want to use `:=` on *either* the `LOGFILE` assignment or on the `DLOG` assignment (or both).

You also need to use the make `$(shell)` function to have make execute the command instead of using backticks to make the shell (run for the recipe line) to do it.

```
LOGFILE=$(shell date +'test_%m.%d_%H.%M.%S.log')
export DLOG:=$(LOGFILE)
test2:
    echo DLOG=$$DLOG
    echo DLOG=${DLOG}
    sleep 2
    echo DLOG=${DLOG}
```

An important thing to note here is that this will cause make to run the command at make parse time and not at recipe execution time.

If you don't want that (because you may not run that target) or you want it to count recipe execution time then you need to do the command execution *in* the recipe and either use a single shell (via line-continuation or [`.ONESHELL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#One-Shell)) or you need to use `$(eval)` in the recipe to force make to expand the simply-expanded make-level variable only at recipe execution time.

Comment: I just tried change to ":=" and "::=".   Both case failed to work for me.  (make on linux, ubuntu 13.10)

Comment: Change to this "LOGFILE := $(shell date +'test_%m.%d_%H.%M.%S.log')"  works now.  THANKS!!!  I accepted your answer!

Comment: Yeah, I *just* realized that you were using shell backticks and not `$(shell)`. I'll update to include that.